# Javascript Date object returns a wrong value for the current date

Tags: javascript

I am having some serious issues with the Date object from the browser. It always seems to return the Summer time instead of keeping account of DST. I tried many solutions but with no avail. I am using moment, moment-timezone but none seem to help me return just the right offset so I can adjust the time sent to the server accordingly. Any ideas how to solve this?

Example: getTimezoneOffset() returns a value of 120, however the time in the date is Thu Apr 03 1986 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the code you've written.

Comment: Share the code Please

Comment: I cannot get a working example that shows what I am currently using because the behavior is different when I run a snippet of the code in jsbin for example

Comment: We cant help you if you don't provide us with something to work with. If you've written code that "sometimes work", then show it to us.

Comment: It seems I did not properly understand what my issue is. Initially I was taking a date from a datepicker, getting the timezone offset from the local machine and calculate an accurate time for the database. What I did not understand was why the selected date by the user was giving a different timezone from the local machine and then it occurred to me that the date's timezone was specific to the selected date. The issue is now fixed.